# Dynamically loaded drop down list from server side are not available to access on submit from server side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

my requirement is store the  drop down list items  filled dynamically(from server side) in a user control on submit button. problem #   On submit button i am unable to get the drop down list items on server side they are null. Can you guys please suggest me what is the best way to acesss the  drop down list  items

on page load

```
ddlCCFirstBTFXMethod.DataSource = tdatasource;
ddlCCFirstBTFXMethod.DataTextField = "Key";
ddlCCFirstBTFXMethod.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlCCFirstBTFXMethod.DataBind();
```

on submit

```
var a = ddlCCFirstBTFXMethod.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToDictionary( i => i.Text,i => i.Value);
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `If(!IsPostBack())` so you code will look something like this.

```
if (!IsPostBack())
{
    ddl.DataSource = source;
    ddl.DataTextField = "Key";
    ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

On Submit

```
foreach(var item in ddl.Items)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("Text : {0}, Value: {1}",item.Text, item.Value);
}
```